# Flask wtf-form override error message

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Im using wtf-form for my password reset page but im having trouble with the generated error messages. I want to be able to either disable the error that wtf-form generates and use my own or be able to override them.

```
{% for e in form.password.errors %}
    <span class="label label-danger">{{ e }}</span>
{% endfor %}

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/setpassword" method=post>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.password, class='form-control', placeholder='Enter Password') }}
    </div>

class PasswordForm(FlaskForm):
password = PasswordField('',validators=[pass_num, pass_small_lett, pass_big_lett, pass_special, pass_min])
confirm = PasswordField('',[validators.EqualTo('password', message='Not matching')])
submit = SubmitField('Send')
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just remove this block:: `{% for e in form.password.errors %}
    <span class="label label-danger">{{ e }}</span>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Thats the block i want to use, I dont want wtf-form to generate the errors for me. This is generated from the form field:
"<p class="help-block">Missing numbers</p>"

Comment: Ah ok, I dont see in your example where these messages come from, but an alternative solution would be to simply set them to `display:none`. So just set: `.help-block{display:none;}`

Comment: Thank you :), im slow today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `form_field()` if you don't want its extra functionality. This will render just the input field:

```
{{ form.password(class='form-control', placeholder='Enter Password') }}
```

In your example the field's label is empty, but in case the field has a label, it must be printed as well. Bootstrap rules are:

- Wrap labels and form controls in <div class="form-group"> (needed for optimum spacing)
- Add class .form-control to all textual <input>, <textarea>, and <select elements

(source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp)